# how to import multiple components as a single component and use them in lazy load

Tags: reactjs, react-router, lazy-loading

I've a condition where I've 3 components

> A.js  B.js  C.js

**In old code**

**routes.js**

```
const A = lazy(() => import("../test/A")); 
const B = lazy(() => import("../test/B")); 
const C = lazy(() => import("../test/C"));


<Route
  path="/test"
  render={({ match: { url } }) => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${url}/a-test`} component={A} />
      <Route exact path={`${url}/b-test`} component={B} />
      <Route exact path={`${url}/c-test`} component={C} />
    </Switch>
  )}
/>
```

**What I want to achieve**

> By the above code we can conclude that every time the separate builds
>   for A, B, C will get download due to lazy load, but I want to achieve
>   a functionality where I can download all 3 of them altogether, i.e.
>   When a download a single component using that only I can download all
>   three of them as a **single separate build**

**What I tried - New Code**

**combine_module.js**

```
import A from "./A";
import B from "./B";
import C from "./C";


const test = {A, B, C};

export default test;
```

**routes.js**

```
const Test = lazy(() => import("../test/combine_module")); 

<Route
  path="/test"
  render={({ match: { url } }) => (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={`${url}/a-test`} component={Test.A} />
      <Route exact path={`${url}/b-test`} component={Test.B} />
      <Route exact path={`${url}/c-test`} component={Test.C} />
    </Switch>
  )}
/>
```

**Code**

[Full code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-raman-mdqzc?file=/src/App.js)

**My Issue**

I don't know about the approach whether it's wrong or right as I'm not getting any error or any warning related to this in the console but **seeing a blank screen cannot see the output**, So can please anybody tell how to make this thing right and achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [React.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy) documentation:

> React.lazy takes a function that must call a dynamic import(). This must return a Promise which resolves to a module with a default export containing a React component.

So the result of `React.lazy` is not a module but a special object `Suspense` can work with.

A usual module can be loaded lazily with WebPack's [dynamic import](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-1). There is a tricky part with this because the module can be loaded after the component was rendered. So two things we need to do:
1) ensure the component does not render `undefined` while module is being loaded
2) update the component when the module has been loaded

Updating is quite simple we can make a hook that will set the module as state on load

```js
function useDynamicModule(path) {
  const [module, setModule] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    import(path).then(setModule, setError);
  }, []);
  return error ? { $error: error } : module.default
}
```

Usage:

```
export default function App() {
  const Test = useDynamicModule("./CombineModule");

  if (!Test) return null;
  if (Test.$error) return "Error";
  return (
    <Router history={history}>
      // ...
    </Router>
  );
}
```

[Playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-snowflake-ybzfg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for this brief explanation, will try implement this, also it always shows me Error on screen, will try to figure out the whole concept

Comment: @Adarsh Do you mean the playground I linked at the bottom of my answer?

Comment: Yes @Shlang the playground, I don't get that